# Need to get string part between two / in a string

Tags: java, indexof

I am new to java need help
the main string i have is 
eg.
"String1/string2/string3/string4/all_free.sdx"
"file1/file2/string3/string4/all_free.sdx"

the end result i need is to be able to isolate and get string3
i can indexof but not able to achieve it in few steps need brainy people help as i am new to JAVA

Comment: Have a look at [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know it's the third item that you want to get, one simple approach could be using [`split` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), like this:

```
String myString = "String1/string2/string3/string4/all_free.sdx";
String string3 = myString.split("/")[2];
```

The call of `split("/")` produces an array of strings like this:

```
{"String1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "all_free.sdx"}
```

Now you can apply the subscript operator to grab the element that you want.